# Open app with iBeacon

Tags: ios, iphone, ibeacon, ios7.1

I'm so excited about the new release of iOs 7.1 with big changes for iBeacon, which is stated in here: http://beekn.net/2014/03/apple-ios-7-1-launches-major-ibeacon-improvement/

and here: http://beekn.net/2014/03/prisoners-dilemma-ios-7-1-challenges-ibeacon-developers/

According to the topic, they said that

> In iOS 7.0 you could just close off the app and it would stop sending
>   you messages. Now, the app doesn’t even need to be open or in the
>   background to work.

As far as I know, you couldn't do anything when an app is closed (not in the background) nor sending any local notification.

So how do you know that if an iOs 7.1 device has enter an iBeacon region?
And if you can catch when a closed app enter an iBeacon region, can you wake it up(open it)?

Comment: None of this is new in iOS 7.1.  The only thing that changed in 7.1 is the behavior after a user kills an app in the task switcher.  That is a very special case that does not sound like what you are describing.  To be clear iOS 7 *ALWAYS* supported background detection of iBeacons and detection after rebooting your phone, even if the app was not manually I restarted

Comment: @davidgyoung
And when you kill an app by task switcher, how do you know when you enter a beacon region? I mean because you killed the app, it can't perform any implementation you've written in it.

Comment: If you enter the region, your "killed" app will restart into the background and you will get a callback on your CLLocationManagerDelegate method.  This is no different than the behavior  if your app had not been killed.  The change in iOS7.1 is that this is no longer blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short yes.
I've implemented this in an app and upon entering the range of the beacon the call is made to:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region;
```

At that point my app is in the background. If it's been terminated re-opened but stays in the background. The class that I have set to be the CLLocationManager delegate receives the callback to the above method and, in my case, posts a local notification.
However you could also trigger opening the app directly.

There's a great little example app on the store called Hide My iPhone by John Yorke. He's opened sourced the code [here](https://github.com/johnyorke/HideMyPhone) and it shows how to set up and respond to beacons in an app.

I also used the guide from Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) to learn more.

Comment: Hi, I'm able to do stuffs in background upon entering a beacon. But I'm still confused with this "In iOS 7.0 you could just close off the app and it would stop sending you messages. Now, the app doesn’t even need to be open or in the background to work"
If you reboot the phone and then not open the app, when you enter a beacon region, how can the app know it??

Comment: @Jozol, even in iOS7.0 your app can be launched after boot by entering a region.  It just has to have been launched once ever (before the reboot) to set up the region monitor.  Your app simply gets a callback as described in my comment on your question.

Comment: It's hugely improved in 7.1 too, considerably more reliable to the point i decided to make 7.1 the minimum OS version to improve user experience.

Answer (score 2):

iOS does launch your app when enters a iBeacon region even if your app was closed completely. You can verify it by doing following things:

1. Define locationManager in AppDelegate, and add delegate CLLocationManagerDelegate;
2. Init locationManager in - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

   ```
   self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
   self.locationManager.delegate = self;
   ```
3. Add methods:

   ```
   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
       if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]) {
           UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
           notification.alertBody = @"didExitRegion";
           notification.soundName = @"Default";
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
       }
   }


   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
       if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]) {
           UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
           notification.alertBody = @"didEnterRegion";
           notification.soundName = @"Default";
           [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: didEnterRegion is called when app is killed but it seems that it doesn't stay in background after. I'm using iOS 11